# wp_nav_menu $theme_location parameter ignored

Tags: menus, documentation

This is the first paragraph of the [documentation of the function `wp nav menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu):

> Given a `theme_location parameter`, the function displays the menu
>   assigned to that location, or nothing if no such location exists or no
>   menu is assigned to it.

However, I am providing a `theme_location` that I have not registered, and in spite of that a menu item appears.

Here's my functions.php:

```
<?php
function register_my_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' ); ?>
```

And here's how I call the menu:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu($args = array('theme_location' => 'nonsense')); ?>
```

On my page, a menu with the default item "Sample page" appears. According to the documentation I cite, nothing should be displayed, because the location "nonsense" should not exist.

Is the documentation wrong, or am I making some mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is wrong. [Check the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L241). There are two telling comments. First there is:

> ```
> // Get the nav menu based on the theme_location
> ```

And after which there is another comment that reads:

> ```
> // get the first menu that has items if we still can't find a menu
> ```

Following that last comment the code runs [`wp_get_nav_menus`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L417) and loops through every menu on the site hoping to find one that has associated items. In other words, `wp_nav_menu` tries desperately to create a menu and will use the first one it finds. I don't understand the logic behind that code. I get the concept of fallbacks, but this strikes me as fallback overkill.

You will need to wrap your code in [`has_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_nav_menu) to prevent this behavior.

```
if (has_nav_menu('nonsense')) {
  wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'nonsense'));
}
```

Comment: In case you want to head/desk a bit more: If no location is defined, you'll get back _all_ nav menu item/`WP_Post` objects no matter what. And yes, it's callback behind callback, senseless amount of `func_get_args()` aligning normal arguments in the method heads, etc. Oh ... and all nicely wrapped up in PHP 4 code. _facepalm_ ... Did I mention that the nav menu is WooThemes creation (a.k.a.: fault)?

Comment: @kaiser: I didn't know that about Wootheme, but a lot of things make more sense now

Answer (score 0):

The documentation was wrong and inconsistent. There is the additional parameter `fallback_cb` which determines what happens if the `menu_location` does not exist. By default, it calls `wp_page_menu` which displays some default menu.

I have corrected the documentation, so this question has been settled.

Thanks to s_ha_dum for pointing me into the right direction!